# Create a react-select for each question with the answers to each question

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have tried these lines of code, but I didn't understand what is the problem, from what I have guessed it may be because react-select must have a valid value which is not the case because for each case it will extract new values of every new question ...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b87ZR.png)

```
{ Object.entries(this.state.list).map( ([key, listValue]) => {                          
    return (                            
        <div className="row ">
            <div className="col-xl-11">
                <h6 className="align-items-center float-left">{key}</h6>
                <div className="text-right">
                   <div className="col-md-11" style={{width: '130px',  height: '20px',top: '-20px', right: '-400px'}}>
                        <Select 
                           name="secondSelectt" 
                           value={this.state.value}
                           multi={true}
                           options={listValue}
                        /> 
                  </div>
```

Comment: What is your question, could you be more specific?

Comment: @yahms23 my question is: is it possible to create many react-select tags with different options values from just one declaration as I did in my code .. otherwise can anyone suggest me a better way of coding it .. ( The picture may help me understand my case .. )

Answer (score 0):

I've done a basic component below:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const listObject = {a:["Answer","another ans"],
                      b:["ans2"],
                      c:["ans33", "bla", "bla4"]}
  
  
  return (
    <div className="App">

      {Object.entries(listObject).map( ([key,values]) => {                          
                 return (
                  <>
                  <h1>{key}</h1>
                          < select 
                          key={key}
                          name = "secondSelectt" 
                          value={key}>

                            {values.map((key,values)=>{
                              return (
                                <option key={key} >{key}</option>)
                            })}

                          </select>
                  </>
                          
                 )})}

    </div>
  );
}
```

Is this what you wanted? I assume the object `liste` you showed was actually an object of question keys and an array of possible answers for values. I did two mappings: one for each `select` tag and one nested for the `options` tag.

There might be a shorter way to do it but this seems to work fine. I removed your styling for simplicity but this can be easily added back in just replace the `<h1>` tag and just map your `key` value however needed.

Comment: can you please verify the url because there is nothing related to my problem it just shows 'Start editing to see some magic happen!'

Comment: I'll type it in

Comment: Yeaah man it worked, I just had to change  values.map((key,values)  by Object.entries(values).map((key,values) because it gave me an error

Comment: Np :) approve my ans if it helped!